# bug in the part title between the number and title

Tags: spacing, titles

the label of the title and number are overlapping and I have 0 experience with latex, the sty file I believe to be sections.sty

in the text is a simple: \part{Part Tres: NPCs}

but in the sty is

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \part
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\thispagestyle{part}\nodesto\fontsize{50pt}{50pt}\selectfont\color{title1}\filcenter}
{\partname \thepart}
{-15pt}
{\Large}

\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-54pt}{0pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \chapter
```

this is the main tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,openany]{book}
%\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[bg-letter]{lib/rpg-book} % Options: bg-a4, bg-letter, 
 bg-full, bg-print, bg-none.
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


% Start document
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{ppl}
\selectfont % Set text font
\frontmatter

\rpgMakeCover[
image = img/part-cover,
logo = img/logo,
title = Memorias da Terra Media e Dru Hill ,
subtitle = Created by Maikon
]

\tableofcontents

% Your content goes here
% ----------------------------------------- 
\chapter{Resumo de Hist\'orias e Contos entre A Terra e Dru Hill}

\mainmatter

\part{Campanhas e Hist\'orias}
```

what matters is the part item, which the definition is in the sty I provided.

also the full design is here:

https://github.com/Krozark/RPG-LaTeX-Template

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There's not enough information here for us to do anything but guess -- different document classes treat parts differently.  Please add a compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that demonstrates the problem, that potential helpers can use to experiment.

Comment: the full code is in https://github.com/Krozark/RPG-LaTeX-Template

Comment: Please copy the relevant code to your question. Links rot over time and thus your question will not be useful to others as they cannot see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is needed is to enlarge the part number box.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,openany]{book}

\usepackage[bg-letter]{lib/rpg-book} % Options: bg-a4, bg-letter, bg-full, bg-print, bg-none.
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\thispagestyle{part}\nodesto\fontsize{50pt}{50pt}\selectfont\color{title1}\filcenter}
{\partname~\thepart}% changed <<<<<<<
{-15pt}
{\Large}

%************************ added <<<<<<<<
\newlength{\extrawidth}% 
\settowidth{\extrawidth}{VIII} % the width of "VIII"
\addtolength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\extrawidth}% expand the box of the part number
%*********************************

% Start document
\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{ppl}
    \selectfont % Set text font
    \frontmatter
    
    \rpgMakeCover[
    image = img/cover,
    logo = img/logo,
    title = Memorias da Terra Media e Dru Hill ,
    subtitle = Created by Maikon
    ]
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    % Your content goes here
    % ----------------------------------------- 

    
    \mainmatter
    
    \part{Campanhas e Hist\'orias}
    \lipsum[1-20]
    
    \part{Personalidades}
    
\end{document}
```